# How i can wrap json response data for djago-rest-framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I use djano rest framework. I have model, serializer and view:

```
class PictureModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=256)


class PictureView(mixins.ListModelMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = PictureSerializer
    queryset = PictureModel.objects.all()

    def get(self, request):
        return self.list(request)


class PictureSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PictureModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

get request return json :

```
[
  {
   "id": 120525, "url": "https://ddd.com/upload/iblock/579/5797cc881f8790926cee4a8fc790d1bd.JPG"
  },
  {
    "id": 120526, "url": "https://ddd.com/upload/iblock/382/382526e1deee07f60871430bd806aa71.JPG"
  }
  ...
 ]
```

But i need wrap this data to

```
{
"success": 1, 
"data": [
     {
      "id": 120525, "url": "https://ddd.com/upload/iblock/579/5797cc881f8790926cee4a8fc790d1bd.JPG"
     },
     {
      "id": 120526, "url": "https://ddd.com/upload/iblock/382/382526e1deee07f60871430bd806aa71.JPG"
     }
     ...
 ]
```

How i can do it? I can use middleware for it but i don't know how i can edit response data. Middleware apply for all requests but i need apply it not for all. May be I can use my renderer but I don't know how.

P.S. Also I use swagger documentation auto generator.

UPDATED 09.08.2021:
I specify. I not like way modify get function because I have many views.

I want next. In view i can throw exception, then catch it and return {'success': 0, 'data': None, 'message': exc.message}. If without exception return {'success': 1, 'data': data}

I can make

```
def get(self, request):
    try:
        # code
        return Response(data={'success': 1, 'data': data})
    except MyException as ex:
        return Response(data={'success': 0, 'data': None, 'message': exc.message})
```

but i don't like it. I try create owned rendere class

```
class ApiRenderer(JSONRenderer):

    def render(self, data, accepted_media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        if 'success' not in data:
            data = {
            'status': 1,
            'data': data
            }
        return super(ApiRenderer, self).render(data=data, accepted_media_type=accepted_media_type,
                                           renderer_context=renderer_context)
```

It works. But if throw exception where i cat catch it, and replace response data?

Answer (score 0):

I like to think simple. How about:

```
def json_wrapper(status=True, data):
    wrapped = {}
    wrapped['status'] = 1 if status else 0
    wrapped['data'] = data  
    return wrapped
```

Can be more flexible using classes but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need `id` as a field in Django, rather it is created automatically for you.

Now, let's solve your problem as the following:

```py
class PictureView(mixins.ListModelMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = PictureSerializer
    queryset = PictureModel.objects.all()

    def list(self, request):
        response = super().list(request)
        return Response({"success": 1 if response.data else 0, "data": response.data})
```